# how to add JAR and .SO file in the Android Sdk

Tags: android

how to add the External JAR file and .so File in the Android Sdk. Can you anyone please
help for this.

Answer (score 1):

**For a JAR ::**

right click on project >> Build path >> Configure Build path >> got to library tab >> add external JAR >> chose from particular location and >>> ok

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. I dont want add the JAR file in the project.I want add the JAR File in Androidsdk itself.do you any idea about this

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project in eclipse go to build path to add external jar files.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply. I dont want add the JAR file in the project.I want add the JAR File in Androidsdk itself.do you any idea about this

Comment: Yes you can,android is open source you can download it from http://source.android.com/ and you can do according to android privacy.

Comment: Thank your reply already I have android source code.i need more detail about this.I am new to android

Comment: if you have source then try to know how to make jar files from java source code.