# Add JAR file in Android sdk

Tags: android

I am new android. How add the JAR file in the android sdk and where to add. Can you 
anyone please help me.

Thanks
Thilak.

Comment: What do you mean with ADD JAR FILE in android sdk???
You mean..how to add JAR file in android project (eclipse)? if so check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project

Comment: which ide are you use? Eclips? then it going to comfortable.show my answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add JAR and .SO file in the Android Sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676293/how-to-add-jar-and-so-file-in-the-android-sdk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For a JAR ::**

right click on project >> Build path >> Configure Build path >> got to library tab >> add external JAR >> chose from particular location and >>> ok

Comment: ya it is for eclipse. in the past i have already done by this steps

Comment: But it creates problem when you pass the same application folder to other person/pc, at that time there will be an error message that library not found.

Answer (score 1):

> This means not in eclipse but we want inside android sdk without using eclipse

You cannot put JARs "inside android sdk", other than in the form of building your own device firmware.

To add JARs to an Android project, put them in the `libs/` directory, and add them to the build path of your IDE if needed (e.g., Eclipse). For command-line builds with Ant, simply having the JARs in `libs/` will suffice.